# What can one do to enjoy death or the dying process?

Tags: death

Death is usually very painful as noted in [this Wikipedia article on Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death):

> Death – particularly the death of humans – has commonly been considered a sad or unpleasant occasion, due to the affection for the being that has died and the termination of social and familial bonds with the deceased. Other concerns include fear of death, necrophobia, anxiety, sorrow, grief, emotional pain, depression, sympathy, compassion, solitude, or saudade. Many cultures and religions have the idea of an afterlife, and also hold the idea of reward or judgement and punishment for past sin.

But what can the dying person do to enjoy their moment of death? What do Hindu scriptures recommend for one's death to be less painful?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79577/discussion-on-question-by-thelittlenaruto-how-can-one-enjoy-death).

Comment: First thing is one should be conscious to enjoy anything or whatever. So, u may ask another Q like "How to remain conscious while dying?"

Comment: @Rickross Yeah I am wondering what should be the body content.

Comment: No need to change anything here now Or are u asking how to frame another Q like I suggested? @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @Rickross Yeah framing another question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How can someone(the one who is dying) enjoy his death moment?

Yes, one can also even enjoy his death hours or last days or death moment, not by doing things pleasurable to him. But through Gyana or right kind of knowledge about life and death.

By  knowing our  true identity,  and purpose of life and the eternal laws of nature with which everybody is bound.

With the right kind of knowledge, faith in supreme creator, being free from all material desires, surrendering to god,  cheerfully accepting the changes jivas undergo throughout his life cycle etc. as told in Hinduism scripture one can stay calm, happy and unaffected even at his death bed as told throughout Hinduism scriptures.

---

It's very common that we face certain conditions during old age or near to death like the fear of death, necrophobia, anxiety, sorrow, grief, emotional pain, depression, sympathy, compassion, solitude, or saudade that do occur in all the human beings.

The Hindu scriptures are are giving us the solution to all this by giving us the in-depth knowledge (Gyana)  about our true identity and process of life and death etc. Thus giving us the moral support and reveling the true secrets , otherwise hidden due to our ignorance.

So Hinduism scriptures urge us to obtain the right kind of knowledge and through which we can overcome all this situations and can enjoy the phenomena of death with cheerful heart.

---

Let's see what Hindu scripture is telling us with which we can fully appreciate death with open and cheerful heart.

## Accepting  of the phenomena of Death  which is unbeatable .

First thing one must accept that death is unavoidable, it's certain to all living beings. And knowing and accepting this phenomena one can avoid the unpleasant situations that will arise due to phenomena of death.

[**Rig-Veda**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v8.157) - **Mandala 10 - Hymn 14 -Mantra 2**  is telling us the exact same thing that was stated above - The Devata of this hymn is Mrityu i.e. death. In this hymn, we can see the mantras which are addressed to the person who is dead or is of old age or near to death. This is an inspirational hymn. Telling us that we will go through the same path our ancestors gone before to meet Yama and Varuna, and asking them to bless us after death.

> यमो नो गातुं प्रथमो विवेद नैषा गव्यूतिरपभर्तवा उ |  
>  यत्रा नः
>   पूर्वे पितरः परेयुरेना जज्ञानाःपथ्या अनु स्वा: || Rv. 10.14.2 ||
>
> yamo no ghātuṃ prathamo viveda naiṣa ghavyūtirapabhartavā u | 
>  yatrā naḥ pūrve
>   pitaraḥ pareyurenā jajñānāḥpathyā anu svāḥ ||
>
> No one  is capable of averting the laws of Yama.

---

And Shree Krishna is telling us the same in [**Shreemad Bhagvat Gita**](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=27&htshg=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&etadi=1) and advising us not to grieve.

> जातस्य हि ध्रुवो मृत्युर्ध्रुवं जन्म मृतस्य च। 
>   तस्मादपरिहार्येऽर्थे न त्वं शोचितुमर्हसि।। BG 2.27।।
>
> jātasya hi dhruvo mṛtyur dhruvaṁ janma mṛtasya ca |
>  tasmād
>   aparihārye ’rthe na tvaṁ śocitum arhasi ||
>
> For certain is death for the born, and certain is birth for the dead;
>   therefore, over the inevitable thou should not grieve.

---

Shree Krishna in [**Bhagavad Gita 2.22**](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=22&htshg=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&etadi=1) is also explaining the reason of our death in order to revive of all above sorrows related to old age and death Shree krishna in below shloka of Shrimad Bhagwat Gita is advising us to know the basic fact, that, as a we throw out worn-garments and puts on new, so the self or Atma cast off its old worn out bodies and enter into others that are new.

> वासांसि जीर्णानि यथा विहाय नवानि गृह्णाति नरोऽपराणि। 
>  तथा शरीराणि
>   विहाय जीर्णा न्यन्यानि संयाति नवानि देही ।। BG 2.22।।
>
> vāsāṁsi jīrṇāni yathā vihāya navāni gṛhṇāti naro ’parāṇi | 
>  tathā
>   śarīrāṇi vihāya jīrṇāny anyāni saṁyāti navāni dehī ||
>
> Just as a man casts off worn-out clothes and puts on new ones, so also
>   the embodied self casts off worn-out bodies and enters others which
>   are new.

---

## Knowing our true nature - we are not the body but the Atman or Brahman itself -:

Hinduism believes that there is Atman (soul, self) in every being which is the essence of an individual. Atman, in Hinduism, is considered as eternal, imperishable, beyond time, "not the same as body or mind or consciousness, but is something beyond which permeates all these". Atman is a metaphysical and spiritual concept for the Hindus, often discussed in their scriptures with the concept of Brahman.

The **Brihadaranyaka Upanishad** describes Atman as that in which everything exists, which is of the highest value, which permeates everything, which is the essence of all, bliss and beyond description.[27] In hymn 4.4.5, Brihadaranyaka Upanishad describes Atman as Brahman (universal absolute; supreme soul), and associates it with everything one is, everything one can be, one's free will, one's desire, what one does, what one doesn't do, the good in oneself, the bad in oneself.

This theme of Ātman, that is soul and self of oneself, every person, every being is the same as Brahman, is extensively repeated in [**Brihadāranyaka Upanishad**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117939.html) . The Upanishad asserts that this knowledge of "I am Brahman", and that there is no difference between "I" and "you", or "I" and "him" is a source of liberation, and not even gods can prevail over such a liberated man.

> तदिदमप्येतर्हि य एवं वेद, **अहम् ब्रह्मास्मीति**, स इदं सर्वम् भवति,
>   तस्य ह न देवाश्चनाभूत्या ईशते, आत्मा ह्येषां स भवति;
>
> tadidamapyetarhi ya evaṃ veda, **aham brahmāsmīti,** sa idaṃ sarvam
>   bhavati, tasya ha na devāścanābhūtyā īśate, ātmā hyeṣāṃ sa bhavati;
>
> And to this day whoever in like manner k(?)s It as, ‘I am Brahman,’
>   becomes all this (?)verse). Even the gods cannot prevail against(?)
>   him, for he becomes their self.

And the understanding  characteristics of this Atman or Brahman is understanding our own true nature or is our true identity. Which is [**Sat-Chit- Ananda**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satcitananda). 
I am of the nature of consciousness. I am made of consciousness and bliss. I am non-dual, pure in form, absolute knowledge, absolute love. I am changeless, devoid of desire or anger, I am detached. I am one essence, un-limitedness, utter consciousness. I am boundless bliss, existence and transcendent bliss.I am the Atman, that revels in itself. I am the Sacchidananda that is eternal, enlightened and pure.

This self is non destructible unlike our body which is subjected to cycle of birth and death, our true self is non perishable.

> न जायते म्रियते वा कदाचि न्नायं भूत्वा भविता वा न भूयः। 
>  अजो
>   नित्यः शाश्वतोऽयं पुराणो न हन्यते हन्यमाने शरीरे।। [**BG
>   2.20**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2/20)।।
>
> na jāyate mriyate vā kadācin nāyaṁ bhūtvā bhavitā vā na bhūyaḥ 
>   ajo nityaḥ śāśvato ’yaṁ purāṇo na hanyate hanyamāne śarīre
>
> For the soul there is neither birth nor death at any time. He has not
>   come into being, does not come into being, and will not come into
>   being. He is unborn, eternal, ever-existing and primeval. He is not
>   slain when the body is slain.

---

## Preparation through true devotion (Bhakti) and surrendering  to lord.

When we truly surrender to god all our doubts, fears, sorrows and worries vanishes. We experience true bliss you make peace with death and watch its devouring power without fear and aversion. As promised by god himself.

> तेषामहं समुद्धर्ता मृत्युसंसारसागरात्।
>  भवामि नचिरात्पार्थ
>   मय्यावेशितचेतसाम्।। [**BG 12.7**](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?htshg=1&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etgb=1&etadi=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=12&field_nsutra_value=7)।।
>
> 12.7 Of those whose minds are thus focused on me, I become soon their savior from the ocean of mortal life.

those who, renouncing all actions in me, and regarding me as the supreme, worship me... For those whose thoughts have entered into me, I am soon the deliverer from the ocean of death and transmigration, Arjuna. Keep your mind on me alone, your intellect on me. Thus you shall dwell in me hereafter.

---

Thus by Bhakti Yoga and surrendering oneself to god one can be free from all the fears that arise from idea of death, in full assurance that the supreme lord will take us out of this ocean of sansara safely and will liberate us or will give us the Moksha , the highest state described in hinduism, we can overcome the fear of death.

So finally this is just short answer of how one can enjoy the moments of death" ** Through spiritual   experience and gaining the knowledge of self ** And this knowledge through which we can understand the death and all its spiritual aspects can be an enjoyable experience. Not the kind of enjoyment in general sense ** but a kind of different divine enjoyment ** in the form of Bliss.

Comment: The central idea of the answer is with the spiritual knowledge  told in scriptures ,we will be able to prepare ourselves and can fully appreciate this phenomenon with all it's knowhow .And then we will not face any sorrow resulting the death. And thus fully free from fear and grief of death we can enjoy the situation with ease and cheerful heart.

Comment: I feel like reading a history answer, Just kidding! :D But Nicely answered with different scripture references.

Comment: The first 2 paras seem like commentary/personal advice. I think the answer should begin with 'Lets see what Hinduism scripture is telling us...'

Comment: Absolutely none of ur quotes say anything regarding what should be done so that one  can "enjoy the dying moments". You may also quote something reagrding how one can remain conscious while dying. Question of feeling good or bad during that time arises only after that is confirmed. @SwiftPushkar

Comment: @sv. - No it is not a personal advice/commentary , but rather we can say a little introduction of what  exactly the answer is about. Actually the title of the question is bit generic  so to isolate the topic   from generic issue and to restrict it to Hinduism some commentary is necessary. But Still i will try to refine those paras and will try to add more quotes in these.:-)

Comment: @Rickross - Yes , those are not the direct quotes , but I think Hinduism scriptures itself apart from Garuda Purana is handling this issue in indirect way i.e. not talking very boldly on this issue because in that it is assured that one should not fear about the death of the body as we are pure consciousness and with proper efforts we can achieve moksha. So this kind of fear issue is irrelevant to the scriptures as we firmly believe in  power of Atma Gyana that will lead us straight to Moksha with proper devotion.:-)

Comment: @Rickross On how to remain consicouness during dying and remember god, there is reference in Srimad bhagavatham Gajendra Moksha. Lord Vishnu says to all those who chant the grajendra moksha stotram daily in the morning as soon they wake, Lord assuring them of his rememberance while. this why its mandated in vidaypeeta of HH Sri Vishwesa swamy that daily morning wake this stotra is chanted without fail. I don't have scriptural reference.. may you or somebody take the exerpts and paste as answer..

Answer (score 7):

The simplest and most effective way to do this is to chant the name of the deity you admire or adore the most be it Vishnu, Shiva or Krishna or any other. Quoting from [Elevation at Death](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bbd/2)

> When we add Kṛṣṇa—or God—to our lives, this human form of life becomes
>   perfect. At the time of death we have to finish that process of
>   perfection. During our lifetime we have to practice the method of
>   approaching that perfection so that at the time of death, when we have
>   to give up this material body, that perfection can be realized.

Basically you need to be devoted fully towards the one whom you worship.

> In the yoga system this process is called pratyāhāra, which means
>   "just the opposite." Although during life the eyes are engaged in
>   seeing worldly beauty, at death one has to retract the senses from
>   their objects and see the beauty within. Similarly, the ears are
>   accustomed to hearing so many sounds in the world, but at the moment
>   of death one has to hear the transcendental oṁkāra from within.
>
> oṁ ity ekākṣaraṁ brahma vyāharan mām anusmaran yaḥ prayāti tyajan
>   dehaṁ sa yāti paramāṁ gatim

Quoting below excerpts from [SC 4](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sc/4): Neither Birth Nor Death which explains that even accidental chanting name of the Supreme Head can ease your death process:

> At the time of death people become very anxious to save themselves,
>   especially those who have been sinful. Of course, the soul itself is
>   not subject to death (na hanyate hanyamāne śarīre [Bg. 2.20]), but
>   leaving the present body and entering into another body is very
>   painful.
>
> When Ajāmila was dying, he saw three ferocious and very frightening
>   persons with ropes in their hands, unruly hair on their heads, and
>   bodily hair like bristles. These assistants of Yamarāja, the
>   Yamadūtas, had come to drag Ajāmila out of his body and take him to
>   the court of Yamarāja. Sometimes a dying man cries out in fear when he
>   sees the Yamadūtas. Ajāmila, too, became very fearful.
>
> Fortunately, even though Ajāmila was referring to his son, he chanted
>   the holy name of Nārāyaṇa, and therefore the order-carriers of
>   Nārāyaṇa, the Viṣṇudūtas, also immediately arrived there. Because
>   Ajāmila was extremely afraid of the ropes of Yamarāja, he chanted the
>   Lord's name with tearful eyes. Actually, however, he never meant to
>   chant the holy name of Nārāyaṇa; he meant to call his son.
>
> Because somehow or other Ajāmila became absorbed in thinking of
>   Nārāyaṇa, or Kṛṣṇa, at the time of death, he immediately became
>   eligible for liberation, even though he had acted sinfully throughout
>   his entire life.

Comment: So devotion can be one of the key. I know one old lady who was pure soul and always pray to God. Before dying, she only told God came to take me with him. And she closed the eyes and died. There was no heart attack or brain disease. It was a peaceful death. +1 nice answer.