# Does the body have to die for the soul to leave the body?

Tags: atma, death, life, jiva

At the time of death the soul leaves the body, but the body also suffers destruction first before the soul leaves the body, like disease, brain failure, etc.

My question is, is it possible for the soul to simply leave the body at the time of it's karmic death without any destruction to the body?

Comment: Do these answer your question [What can one do to enjoy death or the dying process?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28106/647) and [Remain conscious while dying?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34223/647) ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto obviously not, they are asking different questions.

Comment: read this part of the first question:"What do Hindu scriptures recommend for one's death to be less painful?" Is it relevant?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto No dude, I'm asking if it's possible for the soul to leave the body without the body dying.

Comment: Either way I dont have the answer but What do you really mean by destruction of body? The body marking its point of death goes through a systematic process. In a diffrent perspective death is destruction of body, not just the detachment of soul.

Comment: @Proxy When the body dies the soul leaves the body correct? Or in other words, death is when the soul leaves the body as per it's karmic time of death (when it is planned to leave). Normally there has to be some means to kill the body like through a heart attack, etc, and then the soul leaves. What I'm wondering is when it's time for the soul to leave the body as per it's karma, can it just leave it without some cause of death?

Comment: The boy is subject to decay - to the prarabdha karma. A realized soul can know the exact moment when death to the body is to occur and can willfully separate. When the jiva separates, the pranamaya kosha - prana, which is part of the subtle body, withdraws from the physical body - the annamaya kosha. Does a torch give off light if the battery is withdrawn? Decay is inevitable without prana.

Comment: Tamil - "Koodu Vittu Koodu Payardhu" , Sanskrit - "Para-kāya praveśana" - is the yoga/siddha ability to leave your body and take on another.

Comment: Tatvale baba stayed in 38yrs till his death until 90 yrs check video

Comment: Balarama left through brahmaradra and during their stay no sign becoming oldies observed including sukacharya was always I  his teens never aged video proof us tatvale baba recently

Answer (score 3):

Although not accurate but I wanted to post this:

> याक्षक्रक्रमभूमिकावसतयो नाडीषु या: संस्थिता
> या: कायोह्गतरोमकूपनिलया या: संस्थिता धातुषु ।
> उच्छासोर्मिमरुत्तरड्ननिलया निश्वासवासाश्च या-
> स्ता देव्यो रिपुपक्षभक्षणरता नन्दन्तु कौलार्चिता: ॥४ २॥
>
> - **kulavarna tantra 8th Ulhassa 42nd verse**

The sholka specifically describes 'yogis' but it also describes about the movement of 'prana vayu' and the intraction with 'Nadis'. There are three important 'Nadis'- the 'eda', 'pingala' and 'sushumna' these three are responsible for the movement of 'prana'. The 'eda' is to the left as well as the 'pingala' to the right.

Yogis can sense energy at points existing at specific places called 'chakras'. This energy is also associated with 'shiva' and 'shakti'.

Not only the chakras but the energy can also be experienced when the 'prana' moves through these 'Nadis' . This whole energy eats up the 'mrutyu' (death) as if it is its Enemy every time; otherwise the person would have simply died after exhaling.

The whole point of stating this was to display the fact that it's not easy to die, Without breaking down at least a single vital system inside the body. when the body gets destroyed these systems rupture and the person dies. If we consider that the body does not get destroyed and simply the soul leave body, the cause of death would be attributed to the lack of breath. But the lack of breath at least scientifically kills the brain cells and person is identified as 'brain dead'. So, it's not possible for the soul to leave a body without any damage to body.

To know more: https://archive.org/details/ShivaSvarodayaTextWithEnglishTranslationRamKumarRai/page/n5/mode/2up

Comment: See Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 4.4.1-2 for how the subtle body departs the annamayakosha.sheath.